# Which is the most future proof way to plotring pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to figure what is the right way to plot pandas DataFrames as, there seem to be multiple working syntaxes coexisting. I know Pandas is still developing so my question is which of the methods below is the most future proof?

Let's say I have DataFrame `df` I could plot it as a histogram using following pandas API calls.

```
df.plot(kind='hist')

df.plot.hist()

df.hist()
```

Looking at the documentation options 1, 2 seem to be pretty much the same thing in which case I prefer df.plot.hist() as I get auto-complete with the plot name. 'hist' is still pretty easy to spell as a string, but 'candlestick_ohlc' for example is pretty easy to typo...

What gets me confused is the 3th option. It does not have all the options of the first 2 and API is different. Is that one some legacy thing or the actual right way of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended method is `plot._plot_type` this is to avoid the ambiguity in `kwarg` params and to aid in tab-completion see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0170-plot.

The `.hist` method still works as a legacy support, I don't believe there are plans to remove this but it's recommended to use `plot.hist` for future compatibility.

Additionally it simplifies the api somewhat as it was a bit problematic to use `kind=graph_type` to specify the graphy type and ensure the params were correct for each graphy type, the kwargs for `plot._plottype` are specified here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#api-dataframe-plotting which should cover all the args in [`hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html#pandas.DataFrame.hist)

Answer (score 1):

I've always considered [`df.hist()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html#pandas.DataFrame.hist) to be the graphical equivalent to [`df.describe()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html#pandas.DataFrame.describe): a quick way of getting an overview over the distribution of numeric data in a data frame. As this is indeed useful, and also used by a few people as far as I know, I'd be surprised if it became deprecated in a future version.

In contrast, I understand the [`df.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) method to be intended for actual data visualization, i.e. the preferred method if you want to tease a specific bit of information out of your data. Consequently, there are more arguments that you can use to modify the plot so that it fits your purpose, whereas with `df.hist()`, you can get useful distributional plots even with the default settings.

Thus, to answer your question: as I see it, both functions serve different purposes, both can be useful depending on your needs, and both should be future-safe.